# How to make all buttons on a website untabbable

Tags: css, html

Is there a way to make all buttons untabbable using CSS?

Right now I am adding tabindex="-1" to all the buttons on my site but a css rule would reduce the chance of future errors.

**EDIT**

*Since it appears that* this is not possible with pure CSS then a pure javascript or angular solution would be acceptable.

Comment: Why do you want to make buttons "untabbable"?

Comment: because the end user doesn't like that they are tabbable. The system is on a laptop with a touch screen. The user should touch and not accidentally press enter to make a selection.

Comment: That's all very well for a customer who can see. So long as it's a system you have control of hardware for and so on that's all cool, but bear in mind that if you're ever dealing with users who have screenreaders, tabbing is often necessary.

Comment: @chriskelly, you got wrong. You ment unta**p**able. But he ment unta**b**able :)

Comment: thanks. You are right but in this case they can all seem and must be able to see very well to do their job.

Comment: @CKocer: They must be ta**p**able!

Comment: Users will be able to TAP with their touch screen. But TABINDEX = '-1' disables surfing between the buttons with the TAB key on your keyboard.

Comment: So what you're saying, is your users need to be able to tap-dance on a table?

Comment: Its beginning to sound that way! @CKocer. you are right.

Comment: Has your client explored the legal complexities/consequences of (potential) disability discrimination? Seriously, depending on jurisdiction, and circumstance, he may be liable to prosecution for actively making the site unusable to blind, or otherwise physically handicapped, users.

Comment: @DavidThomas: It's not a public website. In fact it's completely offline and targeted at a small but known user base. However, this is a very good point and I will mention it so they may consider any implications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Answer for Pure JavaScript. (Without JQuery etc...)

```
var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
```

this will find all button elements,

```
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
    var button = buttons[i];
    button.setAttribute("tabindex","-1");
}
```

this should work.

### Also you can use JQuery

You can't add attributes to elements using CSS. like 'tabindex', 'id' etc...
You can do it using JQuery

```
$(":button").each(function (i) { $(this).attr('tabindex','-1'); });
```

try this with jQuery

Refer to button selector.
http://api.jquery.com/button-selector/

Comment: Assuming the asker has jQuery on the site in question, that is. Which they didn't mention. Always worth checking if they do before throwing in jQuery answers to a question that doesn't mention jQuery at all.

Comment: If there is a way to do that with **CSS** I'd write it down. I knew he want to do it with CSS but there is no way to do that.

Comment: Site uses angular and so far there is no use of jquery on the site :D. However if there really is no css way to do it then I must consider javascript.

Comment: CSS is just for styling. That's why you can't do it with CSS. I think you have to consider using javascript.

Comment: @CKocer - I'm all about providing alternatives, I just think jumping from CSS straight to jQuery is a jump too far if you don't know people have jQuery in their application. Doing exactly this, but in pure javascript would be ideal, imo.

Comment: The question says “If CSS is not possible then a pure javascript or angular solution would do.”

Comment: This isn’t particularly difficult to do in plain JavaScript. The main problem is to know what “all buttons” means in the question: which elements should be covered? Is it just `button` elements, or is e.g. also `<input type=button>` and `<input type=submit>`?

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela this is a edited question. There is no way to do that in CSS.

Comment: thanks CKocer. Sorry you got down voted! I can only half compensate :)

Comment: The question still suggests primarily jQuery. The initial question asked for CSS solutions, and then the correct answer would be “You can’t”. As to the edited question, you should present a pure JavaScript solution first. And you should say “all `button` elements", not “all buttons”. And the answer to the primary question uses wrong terminology (HTML has attributes, not parameters).

Comment: That's a good point. @CKocer: I agree that the jquery should not be the main part of the answer (maybe a footnote or alternative?).

Comment: Wouldn't the jQuery statement be: $(":button").attr('tabindex','-1'); ?